# contains() function not found

Tags: r

I was going through some sample code then I got stuck in this:

```
for (word in sampleMail) {
    if (contains(categoryFeatures, word)) {
      categoryFeatures[[word]] = categoryFeatures[[word]] + singleOccurrence
```

this is not working as it says

> Error: could not find function "contains"

as of in the whole code `contains()` is not defined so i think it's not a user defined function, I searched also but i am not getting a definition of contains in R , there are other ways like `%in%`. But I want to know is this function `contains()` is an existing function in R? If yes, there any specific package I have to import to use `contains()`?

Comment: `??contains` command would help.

Comment: https://github.com/giorgiosironi/r-bayes-classifier/blob/master/example.r

Comment: @dikesh  Won't work in this case.

Comment: @Pascal thanks for the right code sample , actually in an other website i got a snippet of these so i was confused whether it was a library function as they didn't defined the function.. thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

It's a function of dplyr package. You could install dplyr package then the function 'contains' will work. Good luck!